# function to know if I'm using a pandas method or not

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a function to receive this function I created (`extract_and_transform`). I want this function to return true if inside my function I am using `to_pandas()` and in case I am not using `to_pandas()` I want it to return false

```
def extract_and_transform():
    colunas = ['nome', ' idade', ' cpf', ' ativo', ' nascimento', ' estado']
    df = colunas.to_pandas()
    return True
```

note: ignore the function it's just an example that was passed to me, this function is just the parameter of the function I want to create

I tried to create a function to solve the problem using the [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) library but it didn't work.

```
import dis

def list_func_calls(fn):
    funcs = []
    bytecode = dis.Bytecode(fn)
    instrs = list(reversed([instr for instr in bytecode]))
    for (ix, instr) in enumerate(instrs):
        if instr.opname == "CALL_FUNCTION":
            load_func_instr = instrs[ix + instr.arg + 1]
            funcs.append(load_func_instr.argval)

    return ["%d. %s" % (ix, funcname) for (ix, funcname) in enumerate(reversed(funcs), 1)]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, so what's your question? If you need help with writing this function, then what have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? See [ask]. Python has [standard library modules that can help you work with Python code objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/language.html), are you familiar with them? Like [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) for example, but I'm not sure off the top of my head if it'd be useful in this case.

Comment: Replace `return df` with `return True`, since you are indeed using the `to_pandas()` method you cite, although I'm having trouble understanding (a) why you feel you may encounter a scenario with the code given currently where it *wouldn't* execute that line (and thus necessitate the return of `False` per your specification), nor where you got the idea that a `list` should have an instance method `to_pandas()`.

Comment: `CALL_FUNCTION` should be `CALL_METHOD`. Then your code works, though it doesn't get exactly the result you asked for, i.e. a boolean.